# Recursive ternary search in Java: Divide an array into three parts and search them recursively for a given element

Tags: java, recursion, ternary

I'm trying to implement a ternary search in a java array for a given element. At this point I get a StackOverflowError in the lower and upper thirds of the array, and an incorrect result in the middle third. Help much appreciated.

```
public class TernarySearch {

    static int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    public static int search(int[] a, int x, int low, int high) {
    // int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    int thirdile = a.length / 3;
//  System.out.println(a.length/3);
//  System.out.println(thirdile);

    if (low > high) {
        System.out.println("low is greater than high. Item not found.");
        return 0;

    } else if (x > a[(high-(thirdile - 1))]) { // upper third
        System.out.println("X is greater than mid. higher third.");
        return search(a, x, (high - thirdile), high);
    } else if (x > a[thirdile - 1] && x < (high -thirdile)) { // middle third
        System.out.println("X is in the middle third.");
        return search(a, x, thirdile + 1, (high - thirdile) - 1);

    } else if (x < a[thirdile -1 ]) { // lower third
        System.out.println("X is less than thirdile. lower third.");
        return search(a, x, low, thirdile);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Found it at first thirdile");
        return thirdile;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(search(ints, 2, 0, ints.length - 1));
}
```

}

Comment: this `&& x < (high -thirdile)` seems unnecessary

Comment: I want to segment the search into three thirds (as you would with two halves) so it's meant to demarcate middle third portion of the array. Without it the search would span two thirds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you aren't decreasing/increasing the bounds correctly.  For example, the first time you call on the top third you are checking if x is larger than the value at position high-(thirdile - 1) which is index 6.  But you are passing as the index for the low the value 5, when you should be passing the value 7 for the low.  This might lead to never actually isolating the value in the top third... I imagine there is a similar error in the low and mid.

Comment: Thanks. I'm passing as the index for the low (high - thirdile), which is 7, not five. The value is isolated properly. The recursion just never ends, leading to the StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I know that this problem is old. But I though I would post an answer for future people who are looking this up. Your code does some weird things with the thirdile. 
also in your if statements are not all inclusive. You are missing different -1 or have -1 when you shouldn't. Also in your recursive calls you don't always change the low or high to what it should be. Hopefully this code will help people out

```
public class TernarySearch {  
    static int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    public static int search(int[] a, int key, int low, int high) {
        // int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        //int thirdile = (high + low)/3
        int firstThird = ((high+1)-low)/3;
        int secondThird = ((2*((high+1)-1))/3);
        //  System.out.println(a.length/3);
        //  System.out.println(thirdile);

        if (low > high) {
            System.out.println("low is greater than high."+ key +" not found.");
            return -1;

        } else if (key > a[secondThird]) { // upper third
            System.out.println("key is greater than secondThird. its in higher third.");
            return search(a, key, secondThird+1, high);
        } else if (key > a[firstThird]) { // middle third
            System.out.println("key is in the middle third.");
            return search(a, key, firstThird+1, secondThird);
            // high is secondThird, because it could be equal to the secondThird still
            // all we know is that it wasn't higher than a[secondThird], but was higher
            //than a[firstThird]
        } else if (key < a[firstThird]) { // lower third
            System.out.println("key is less than thirdile. lower third.");
            return search(a, key, low, firstThird-1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Found it at first third at index: "+firstThird);
            return firstThird;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(search(ints, 2, 0, ints.length - 1));//print out the index number that is returned
        //if it is -1 that is printed out, 2 wasn't found, else it was found
        int myKeyIndex = search(ints, 2, 0, ints.length-1);
        if(myKeyIndex != -1)
            System.out.println(ints[myKeyIndex]+ "was found in the array!!");
        else
            System.out.println("Didn't find the key!!");
    }

}
```